onCancel function has no animation in Ant Design
I use Modal Component from Ant Design and I notice that once Modal is opened up there's normally an animation showing. However, when I cancel or close the modal, there's just flicker and no animation at all. This behavior happens to only one of my component while others don't.
<div id="view-detail-modal"></div>
                    {selectedBookingIndex !== null &&
                        viewModalVisible &&
                        createPortal(
                            <Modal
                                open={viewModalVisible}
                                onCancel={(e) => {
                                    setViewModalVisible(false);
                                    setSelectedBookingIndex(null);
                                }}
                                footer={null}
                                key={
                                    userBookings[selectedBookingIndex]
                                        .booking_id
                                }>
                                <EachBooking
                                    key={
                                        userBookings[selectedBookingIndex]
                                            .booking_id
                                    }
                                    selectedBooking={
                                        userBookings[selectedBookingIndex]
                                    }
                                    showBackButton={false}
                                />
                            </Modal>,
                            document.getElementById("view-detail-modal")
                        )}

Here is a snippet of the issued modal.
I want to have animation transition of Modal in both in and out.
